# Creating Dynamic object/array from multiple arrays - Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

It might be little complicated question,

I have 2 Arrays in **javascript**

1. rows
2. combined

> ```
>  rows = [
>            ["0324444444", "3510254373", "35000", "5000"],
>            ["0323434444", "3510466773", "32000", "5300"],
>            ["0324444564", "3310254373", "32300", "5450"]
>     ]
> ```
>
> `combined  = [['mobile', 0], ['cnic', 1], ['salary', 2], ['tax', 3]]`

Now i want to merge (or can say "Make a third array out of them") them like this.

[image]

Comment: Whatever you have attempted should be posted as a [mcve]

Comment: Why are `500` and `350` listed as expected values of resulting array?

Comment: The first array of arrays in the scant code provided doesn't match the images. Is there a process in which the code becomes what is portrayed in the useless images?

Comment: @guest271314 . Sorry for confusion. In images those are just sample values to show what is desired and current status.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be done this way

```js
var rows = [
           ["0324444444", "3510254373", "35000", "5000"],
           ["0323434444", "3510466773", "32000", "5300"],
           ["0324444564", "3310254373", "32300", "5450"]
    ]
var combined  = [['mobile', 0], ['cnic', 1], ['salary', 2], ['tax', 3]]

var final = [];
rows.forEach(function(item){
     var newitem = {};
     combined.forEach(function(rowItem, index){
          newitem[rowItem[0]] = item[rowItem[1]];
     })
     final.push(newitem);
});

console.log(final)
```

Comment: Sir, Amazing. I just had to change `newitem[rowItem[0]] = item[rowItem[1]];` to `newitem[rowItem[1]] = item[rowItem[0]];` to get the desired result. Awesome.

Answer (score 2):

Simply try

```js
var rows = [
  ["0324444444", "3510254373", "35000", "5000"],
  ["0323434444", "3510466773", "32000", "5300"],
  ["0324444564", "3310254373", "32300", "5450"]
];
var combined = [
  ['mobile', 0],
  ['cnic', 1],
  ['salary', 2],
  ['tax', 3]
];
var output = rows.map(function(item) {
  var obj = {};
  combined.forEach(function(key) {
    obj[key[0]] = Number(item[key[1]])
  });
  return obj;
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(output, 0, 4));
```